How do you turn a command for a single active cell into a command for a range of cells?
so I'm a beginner to Apps Script. I'm currently trying to create a dropdown on Google Sheets so that users can select multiple options from the drop down. The code I currently have is below, and works well for one cell. However, I was wondering if there was a way to expand on it so that it could be applied to an entire column of cells. (visa vi: I don't have to make a new script for each individual cell I want to use).
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 6 && activeCell.getRow() == 14 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Film Festivals") {
  var newValue = e.value;
  var oldValue = e.oldValue;
  if (!newValue) {
  activeCell.setValue("");
  } else {
  if (!oldValue) {
  activeCell.setValue(newValue);
  } else {
  activeCell.setValue(oldValue + ',' + newValue);
  }
  }
  }
}


Data validation might be a better choise for a dropdown: https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/10107325?hl=en

Here's an idea to work on a range of cells.
Use getActiveSheet instead of getActiveCell to access the active sheet.
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editedRange = e.range;

  // Check if editing is in column 6 (modify as needed) and "Film Festivals" sheet
  if (editedRange.getColumn() === 6 && sheet.getName() === "Film Festivals") {
    var values = editedRange.getValues(); // Get all values in the edited range

    // Loop through each value in the range
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var newValue = values[i][0]; // Access the value at the current row
      var oldValue = editedRange.getValue(i + 1, 1); // Get the previous value for the same row

      if (!newValue) {
        editedRange.setValue(i + 1, 1, ""); // Set empty string if new value is empty
      } else {
        if (!oldValue) {
          editedRange.setValue(i + 1, 1, newValue); // Set new value if no old value
        } else {
          editedRange.setValue(i + 1, 1, oldValue + ',' + newValue); // Append new value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Feel free to customize depending on your need. I hope this helps!
